# Hibernate SQL mixes two column values from different tables

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I am running this query

```
        Query q = session.getCurrentSession()
            .createSQLQuery("SELECT alt.*, cpp.*, l.*, u.*, br.*,np.*, afp.*, lmp.*  FROM ActiveLoansTable alt " +
                    "JOIN loan l ON l.loanId=alt.loanId " +
                    "JOIN custpaymentplan cpp ON cpp.loanId=alt.loanId " +
                    "JOIN branches br ON br.branchId=l.branch_id " +
                    "JOIN users u ON u.userId=l.userId " +
                    "JOIN naturalPerson np ON np.personId=l.customerId " +
                    "LEFT JOIN additionalfinancialparameters afp on afp.loanId = l.loanId " +
                    "LEFT JOIN loanmanagementprice lmp on lmp.loanId = l.loanId " +
                    "WHERE l.status = :statusActive and (alt.isLateInSchedule=1 or alt.isLateOutSchedule=1) ")
            .addEntity("alt", ActiveLoanTable.class)
            .addEntity("cpp", CustPaymentPlan.class)
            .addEntity("l", Loan.class)
            .addEntity("u", User.class)
            .addEntity("br", Branch.class)
            .addEntity("np", NaturalPerson.class)
            .addEntity("afp", AdditionalFinancialParameters.class)
            .addEntity("lmp", LoanManagementPrice.class);
```

then I cast results to objects:

```
        for (Object[] row : rows) {

        ActiveLoanTable alt = (ActiveLoanTable) row[0];
        CustPaymentPlan cpp = (CustPaymentPlan) row[1];
        Loan l = (Loan) row[2];
        User u = (User) row[3];
        Branch br = (Branch) row[4];
        NaturalPerson np = (NaturalPerson) row[5];
        AdditionalFinancialParameters afp = (AdditionalFinancialParameters) row[6];
        LoanManagementPrice lmp = (LoanManagementPrice) row[7];}
```

where `naturalPerson` and users both have column `firstname` and `lastname`. I want to return both of them but in the end result `naturalperson` values are overriden by users values. so `np.firstname` becomes `u.firstname`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL inner join two tables with the same column names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3365494/sql-inner-join-two-tables-with-the-same-column-names)

Comment: Why are you using this method for querying?  Instead, consider just using HQL directly.

Comment: So it is impossible to do with sql query? I prefer it this way